# What are the different states in Clear Quest defect life cycle

Tags: testing, clearquest

I have not been using ClearQuest Web for a long time.Can anybody please tell the different states of the defects and its corresponding CQ status ?

Comment: ClearQuest lets you create your own state model. You pick the states/actions.

Answer (score 0):

The different states of the defects in CQ Web are:

```
> 1.New (Tester)
> 2. Estimate (Project management)
> 3.In Development(Developer)
> 4.Fix Complete(Developer)
> 5.Send to Release
> 6.Deferred
> 6.InAcceptance test
> 7.InInteration test
> 8.Insystem test
> 9.In release
> 10.Ready to Develop
> 11. Ready to test
> 12. Under Investigation
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your schema using  ClearQuest Designer and check State Transition Matrix.